# Pattern printing using js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

How do we print pattern like this in javascript in console not with document.write()?
*
*#
*#*
*#*#
*#*#*

I tried this but it' not working

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 5: i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (j % 2 == 0) {
        console.log("#".repeat(j))
        }
        else {
          console.log("*".repeat(i))
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: So build a string, write at end of line

Comment: JS is case-sensitive, `For` should be `for`. And you're missing a `}`

Comment: Actually, you're missing the `)` in the `console.log` calls.

Comment: You say you want to print `*`, so why are you logging `i`?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` is not intended as a general purpose output stream, there's little ability to customize the layout. You can't call it multiple times and get the output on the same line. If you want output on a single line, it has to be a single call.

Instead of the inner loop, calculate the number of repetitions of `*#` from `i/2`, and append another `*` when `i` is odd.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log('*#'.repeat(Math.floor(i/2)) + (i % 2 ? '*' : ''));
}
```